# In below function on certain condition the while loop doesn't break and it goes into a loop. any idea what condition could be erroneous in procedure

Tags: c, while-loop, logic, break

/*This function removes a node from the queue */

```
static void irp_rmq(IO_REQUEST_QUEUE *q, IO_REQUEST *e)
{
    IO_REQUEST *irp = NULL;

    
    if (!q && !e)
        return;

    irp = q->head;

    if (irp == e) {
        q->head = e->master_next;
        e->master_next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        while (irp && irp->master_next != e)
            irp = irp->master_next;
        
        if( irp && irp->master_next != NULL )
          irp->master_next = irp->master_next->master_next;
      
        e->master_next = NULL;
    }
    q->qlen--;

    return;
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what the current state of any of these variables are.  Having said this: `irp->master_next` -- What if this is an uninitialized pointer or a pointer to memory that is not valid to point to?  You will be looping into hyperspace.  Also, what language are you using, C or C++?  Tag the actual language you're using.

Comment: its a C language program

Comment: It probably gives you a infinite loop if `irp` is equal to `irp->master_next` at one moment. This means you probably have an `IO_REQUEST` that is self referring in `master_next`, you should add `assert` in the feeding code for `IO_REQUEST_QUEUE` to prevent any self referring `IO_REQUEST` to be added on the `IO_REQUEST_QUEUE`. It could be also a circular self reference, some `irp->master_next` points to an initial `irp`, which gives you also an infinite loop. In this case, you should check also the feeding code to prevent that.

Comment: OT: `if (!q && !e)` is true only if **both** pointers are NULL.